# JS - Auto Change Inheriting Classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, visual-studio-code, extends

Is there a way in JS to automatically change the inheriting classes's constructors?

For example, lets say there's a `class Item` and it takes attributes such as `name, brand, price`.

Now I have like 10 other classes that extends this base class, and in case I want to add an attribute to that base class, I'll need manually to add that attribute to all of the extending classes.

seems like a bad practice in my eyes, will anyone enlighten me? is there a better way to do it? or even an extension to help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass all the arguments in extending classes, you don't need to do that.

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

Or if you prefer to name the argumenst in argument object

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {name, brand, price} = props;
}
```